# resource for javascript without jQuery

Tags: javascript

Is there any repository of code snippets, tutorials, whatever, that concentrates on pure JS, without the use of frameworks?
I first approached javascript through scriptalicious then jumped to jQuery. I am now a seasoned jQuery developer, and I've done quite a lot in jQuery throughout the years.
My problem is, I've almost never coded in pure JS. By the time I got advanced in coding in general (I mean, cross-language), my JS coding style relied already heavily on jQuery.
Plus, each time I research a solution for a problem, the first results (or pages of results) in google involve jQuery, or, more rarely, another Js framework. Which leads me to this problem: since I have developed a lot of custom plugins, some fairly complex, for jQuery, I am quite sure I do know a lot of JS. But *I can't tell the difference*!
So I decided that from now on, and as long as I feel the need, I am going to try to use pure JS, at least at the beginning of each project (leaving myself enough time to revert to good old jQueryScript if I get stuck). My problem is I am way too advanced to follow beginner's tutorials. I would like to know if any of you guys has a suggestion for a place to begin my training. Some website where I could learn advanced JS, without frameworks.

Comment: Why?  Libraries make your coding time more efficient and often more cross-browser.  What are you really hoping to learn by coding without a library?

Comment: You can start from here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript most useful and complete source for javascript

Comment: @jfriend00 if you do not know the basics i.e. JavaScript, how you can write a lib or know how to properly extend it?

Comment: jQuery mostly abstracts DOM interfaces and has a limited utility/language extension tool-set. Do I get it right that you want to learn W3C DOM and Microsoft browser inventions?

Comment: I think you need a particular objective in mind to go learn something.  If you want to learn how to do something without any JS lib, then pick a problem that's worth solving without a lib and work to solve it.  As it is, the question is just too abstract.  Very few people write significant extensions without basing them on a lib these days because it's so much more work to do everything from scratch.  I personally find that I learn a lot about native JS by looking at the lib code and debugging through it to see what it's actually doing even while using it.

Comment: @jfriend00: I have a particular objective in mind. I was doing a fairly complex slider that wasn't running smoothly, whatever efforts I was putting in it. After profiling my JS, I noticed the two main bottlenecks were jQuery's data() and functions related to styles and css. I figured I don't need all the fancy parsing jQuery does to help me write faster. I'd rather put the burden on me and not on the browser. So I rewrote whole parts to use native functions, and my slider began to run significantly smoother. I didn't change anything to the code logic, just replaced methods.

Comment: then I kept refactoring and noticed that while optimizing, the only part of jQuery I kept was the selector facilities (just sizzle.) I ended up ditching that too and relying on native JS for selectors. Seeing how much more speed I got, I decided I would never use jQuery for anything but prototyping. But during the time I was browsing the net for answers to my numerous questions about JS, I got extremely frustrated because most answers boiled down to "use jQuery". I love jQuery and have great respect for it, but we should know our basic tools before using it imho.

Comment: Like any library, there are good ways to use it and bad ways to use it.  CSS selectors (whether delivered by Sizzle or even built-in browser functions) are one of those things that can be fast or slow depending upon what you're doing.  If you're throwing out all use of libraries because you once experienced some slowness, the good luck to you going forward.  That would be like me saying that because assembly language worked faster for me in several projects, I should do everything in assembly language.  It simply isn't an effective way to do most development.  Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think Resig's book, Pro Javascript Techniques would be a great fit. I read it a while ago and my memory of it was that he walked through a lot of the kinds of cross browser issues one can experience with Javascript and talks about how one could create code to help remediate those issues.

Ultimately that thinking is what jQuery is all about, but this book is not a jQuery book at all, more focused on JavaScript, approaching the same kinds of problems jQuery makes you not have to think about.

Might be a great fit for where you are, and it is by no means a beginner book.

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-JavaScript-Techniques-John-Resig/dp/1590597273/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1310240944&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597273)

Comment: This seems really interesting. I had not thought of a book (I was thinking more something along the lines of snipplr or sharepoint, but frameworks would be banned), but the book you are proposing indeed targets my needs. Plus, it's John Resig. I like how he writes.

Comment: @Xananax, i forgot to mention this one. It is a good book if you want to understand how something like jQuery was built. Books in general will give you a more structured way to understand a subject then a collection of web posts here and there. If you want *pure JS* that doesn't concern DOM at all see the Good Parts book that I recommended, which is really excelent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want learn more about JavaScript in general and really master it, there are two books that I would recommend:

1. [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805531)
2. [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748)

Both are excellent resources with great depth and cover fairly advanced topics.

If you would like to explore the possiblities of JS outside the browser and explore some cutting edge JS then take a look at the [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/) projects.

Comment: Both yours and jk1's answers suit me, but I marked his as accepted 'cause he has less rep. Thanks all the same!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this Google group:

[http://groups.google.com/group/jsmentors](http://groups.google.com/group/jsmentors?pli=1)

Comment: Is it really a good idea to start learn from a discussion forum?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't really fit my needs. I need a place I can read about javascript or research snippets of code to study, laid out in an organized manner. A forum requires involvement on my part, and my time is scarce. Furthermore, I abhor google groups. I always feel lost there.